# Borderless CRichEditCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cricheditctrl

Is it possible to have borderless CRichEditCtrl control, basically what i want, to have something like Search Edit Box, so either i can put Image at the extreme Right that would be good enough otherwise planning to implement borderless CRichEditCtrl  and will draw Image extreme to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Create the control without WS_BORDER and WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE and WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE.

In MFC land you could create a derived class from CRichEditCtrl and modify these styles in PreCreateWindow.